# Is it possible to mount a CIFS volume using a credentials file against the LOCAL driver?

Tags: docker

I'm aware that plugins like `docker-volume-netshare` exist and I've used them in the past but for this project I am constrained to the local driver only.

I can successfully create and use a CIFS volume with the local driver in the traditional sense (passing it the username/password inline) but now I want to pass the credentials via a credentials file. The Docker documentation says it supports similar commands as mount so, to that end, I've been trying to pass the credentials like I would if I were mounting it via the `mount` command.

I have a `/root/.cifs` file.

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```

Then I tested it by mount manually

```
mount -t cifs \
-o credentials=/root/.cifs,vers=3.0 \
//192.168.76.20/docker_01 /mnt
```

It works successfully and I can read/write data. So now I try to create the docker volume using the same logic.

```
docker volume create \
--driver local \
--name persistent \
--opt type=cifs \
--opt device=//192.168.76.20/docker_01 \
--opt o=credentials=/root/.cifs,vers=3.0
```

However, when I try to use the volume I get `CIFS VFS: No username specified` in the Docker log file.

I tried modifying the volume parameters by including the username (`--opt o=credentials=/root/.cifs,username=docker01,vers=3.0`) but that just results in `0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

Is there a way to create a CIFS volume without having to specify the credentials inline?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing a similar problem: I don't want to have the password in clear on the command line.

Comment: @Jonathan did you guys ever find a solution where you don't have to put your credentials in the compose file?

Comment: @Peter: It seems possible to create an `.env` file in the smae folder as your compose file with somthing like `PASSWORD=my_secre_password` and then use `o: ...,password=${PASSWORD}, ...` via interpolation in the actual compose file. If you DONT'T use `env_file` attribute in your compose file, the password will not be present as environment variable inside the container.

Answer (score 9):

I just digged into this to find out why it does not work. It seems the issue here is that the credentials-file is a feature of the wrapper binary "mount.cifs" while [docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/7b9275c0da707b030e62c96b679a976f31f929d3/vendor/github.com/moby/sys/mount/mounter_linux.go#L30) uses the [systemcall SYS_MOUNT](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/35b2ab0089ea3ee6aace3725af1e000ea04a8ea1/unix/zsyscall_linux.go#L367) itself for mounting the volume:

If you look into [the linux kernel's cifs extension](https://github.com/smfrench/smb3-cifs-linux-stable-backports/blob/0d32bd1285c01d50668acf1551a3543ff2f90b80/Documentation/filesystems/cifs/README) it says:

> When using the mount helper mount.cifs, passwords may be specified via alternate
> mechanisms, instead of specifying it after -o using the normal "pass=" syntax
> on the command line:

You can trace this down to the [source code of the mount.cifs executable](https://git.samba.org/?p=cifs-utils.git;a=blob;f=mount.cifs.c;h=7f898bbd215ab97a01a65a1c5a13378245eacce4;hb=HEAD) where you find the code to read the credentials file.

From this I conclude that unless you change the docker source code to use the mount.cifs executable instead of the linux system call this will not work.